# #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query:

```
    SELECT tb_fifeiroInscricao.*,
       tb_pagseguro.StatusTransacao,
       tb_fifeiro.ds_nome,
       tb_fifeiro.gametag
FROM tb_fifeiroInscricao
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT MAX('tb_pagseguro.id_pagamento')
   FROM tb_pagseguro
   GROUP BY tb_pagseguro.Referencia)
INNER JOIN tb_fifeiro ON (tb_fifeiroInscricao.id_fifeiro = tb_fifeiro.id_fifeiro)
```

And it's giving this error:

**#1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias**

Comment: http://bit.ly/1ibcOww

Comment: -1 because you have failed to Google the error message and stumble on *many* StackOverflow questions answered.

Comment: Apart from the syntactical error you have another error. You are not using in any way the data from the left join. You'll have to rethink your query.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT tb_fifeiroInscricao.*,
       tb_pagseguro.StatusTransacao,
       tb_fifeiro.ds_nome,
       tb_fifeiro.gametag
FROM tb_fifeiroInscricao
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT MAX(tb_pagseguro.id_pagamento)
   FROM tb_pagseguro
   GROUP BY tb_pagseguro.Referencia) tb1
   ON tb1.id_pagamento = tb_fifeiroInscricao.id_pagamento
INNER JOIN tb_fifeiro ON (tb_fifeiroInscricao.id_fifeiro = tb_fifeiro.id_fifeiro)
```

**1st:** you don't have aliases for your tables/sub-queries.

**2nd:** you don't have condition for your `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: Why did you replace `tb_fifeiroInscricao` with `tb1`?

Comment: @MostyMostacho, because I put a `tb1` as alias of the sub-query.

Comment: The join is on `tb_fifeiroInscricao`. Not in the derived table. You're changing the logic of the statement.

Comment: I stand corrected. I don't noticed the LEFT JOIN

Comment: Ok but after the edit `tb1.id_pagamento` will result in another error because you're not exporting field `tb1.id_pagamento` :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT tb_fifeiroInscricao.*,
   tb_pagseguro.StatusTransacao,
   tb_fifeiro.ds_nome,
   tb_fifeiro.gametag
FROM tb_fifeiroInscricao tb1
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT MAX(tb_pagseguro.id_pagamento)
FROM tb_pagseguro
GROUP BY tb_pagseguro.Referencia) tb2
ON tb1.id_pagamento = tb2.id_pagamento
INNER JOIN tb_fifeiro tb3 ON (tb1.id_fifeiro = tb3.id_fifeiro)
```